# What does object with parentheses in place of keys in TypeScript mean?

Tags: json, typescript, object, types, parentheses

What does object with parentheses in place of keys in TypeScript mean?

E.g. here

```
foo(success: { (): void; (): void; }) {}
```

I can not understand what does the `success` parameter represent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{ (): void; (): void; }` is just a [callable type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures). The second `(): void` is a [function overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads). Though in this case it does nothing. In less magical way it could be written as:

```typescript
interface Success {
  (): void
  (): void
}

function foo(success: Success) {}
```

This is mostly equivalent to `foo(success: () => void) {}`.

Comment: `This is mostly equivalent to foo(success: () => void) {}.` But what does the second function signature mean? `(): void`??

Comment: That's just a function overload. The very same function in javascript can accept different number of arguments of different types. So it's not uncommon to have an interface like that: `{ (): void; (n: number): void; }` meaning the function can accept either no arguments or one `number` argument as well. Though in this particular case the second overload just does nothing still being syntacticaly acceptible.

Comment: Hm. Strange. VS Code suggests me to use exactly the `{ (): void; (): void; }` instead of simply the `() => void`.

Comment: They are absolutely interchangable from typescript's point of view. https://tsplay.dev/NVnE5N